# Get PGP Fingerprint key in c#

Tags: c#, fingerprint, pgp

I just want to know if there is a c# lib to get the key fingerprint such "B97E 9964 ACAD 1907 970D  37CC 8A9E 3745 558E 41AF".

I currently use BouncyCastle to encryption/decryption and to make signature but it seems that BC has not a function to get it, but in Java do.

I want to precise that I use OpenPGP keys defined as RFC 4880 and not X509 or others.

I try to search on GitHub, this forum but i don't find anything about it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same lib and could not find anything.

The PGP object has a property called Key ID but its just a negative number

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l31cD.png)

Edit:

Nvm i think i found it https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp/PgpPublicKey/GetFingerprint/php-pgppublickey-getfingerprint-method-examples.html

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Try to share code as text, wrapped by code fence or snippet. Avoid images which just contain code.